# non attached element width not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I'm trying to find a solution in Chrome. In Firefox, I can get the size (from CSS) of an element without attaching/displaying it by doing:

```
var elem = $('<div class="someclass"></div>');
var w = elem.width();
console.log(w);
```

FF gives me the right size, but Chrome always returns 0. Any work around?

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/g4kk4wr7/)

Comment: All of these solutions have me attaching to the DOM. I guess there is no solution if using Chrome and not attaching.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All of these solutions have me attaching to the DOM. I guess there is no solution if using Chrome and not attaching.

Answer (score 1):

this is some strange behavior of some browsers.

i have however found a solution:

```
var elem = $('<div class="someclass"></div>').hide();
$('body').append(elem);
var width = elem.width();
elem.remove();
console.log(width);
```

Comment: thanks I already know that answer. I was trying, as the question states, to find a way NOT to attach.

Comment: i know but can't find a way to simulate this in a way that it isn't attached

Answer (score 0):

Try to get selector by **ID** or **Classname**.   [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/xry09unz/)

```
var elem = $('<div class="someclass"></div>');
var w = $(".someclass").width();
console.log(w);
```

It will work in all browser;

Comment: It workes in chrome. Check JSfiddle. And in your example you are not creating any HTML or appending any HTML code using javascript then how it will work.

Comment: Please READ the question. I DO NOT WANT TO ATTACH TO DOM.

Comment: Sorry. Then different browser will render in different way.